# Magento send post with CSV

Tags: email, magento, csv, attachment

I have a form that gets emailed to the store owner. Nothing fancy, just a bunch of input fields and select fields.

I am attempting turn this into a CSV file that gets attached to the email.

In my controller, I have:

```
    public function postAction() {
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ($post) {
        #Mage::log($post,null,'tmp.log');

        #not using this at the moment...
        $postObject = new Varien_Object();
        $postObject->setData($post);


        $file = fopen('temp/temp.csv','w+');

        foreach($post as $sections) {
            fputcsv($file, $sections);
        };

        fclose($file);

        $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('training_email_template');
        $mailTemplate->setSenderName('Joe Schmoe');
        $mailTemplate->setSenderEmail('eat@joes.com');
        $mailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Form Submission');
        $attachment = $mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment($file);
        $attachment->filename = 'file.csv';

        $mailTemplate->send(
            'store@owner.com',
            Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
            $post
        );
    }
}
```

Now the file itself gets created, I can open temp.csv just fine and it looks like it is supposed to. However, the file that is getting attached is empty or (when I tried a few other things) the encoding would be all wonky... clearly not in the proper format.

Feel like I'm just missing something simple here... anyone have some advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're sending a file resource as the parameter to `createAttachment()`. It should be a string. Try this:

```
$mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment(
    file_get_contents('temp/temp.csv'),
    Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
    Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
    'file.csv'
);
```

Here's the documentation for [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.attachments.html)

```
/**  
 * Creates a Zend_Mime_Part attachment
 *
 * Attachment is automatically added to the mail object after creation. The
 * attachment object is returned to allow for further manipulation.
 *
 * @param  string         $body
 * @param  string         $mimeType
 * @param  string         $disposition
 * @param  string         $encoding
 * @param  string         $filename OPTIONAL A filename for the attachment
 * @return Zend_Mime_Part Newly created Zend_Mime_Part object (to allow
 * advanced settings)
 */
public function createAttachment($body,
                                 $mimeType    = Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                                 $disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                                 $encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                                 $filename    = null)
```

Comment: I was looking all over for the doc on that function... I fail Google today. Thanks!